# How detect if audio only when playing MP4 HEVC (h265) video files in incompatible browsers?

Tags: video, browser, mp4, hevc

I'm using a native `<video>` tag and I've seen that many browsers can't play mp4 videos using hevc/h265 codec:

https://caniuse.com/hevc

Currently, as default behavior, uncompatibles browsers (chrome & firefox mainly) just play video with audio only like if everything was ok.. I would like to properly tell users their browser can't play this specific video.

Do you know if there's a way to detect if video is not played correctly (audio only) on frontend side to alert end users?

ps: Reencoding videos to another format is not the question asked there :)

Comment: Basically you must load (into JS array) a small section (_eg:_ 32kb) of the video bytes to check the MP4 header for codec type... Are these videos coming from user's own uploading (via file browse) or just video coming from a server? IF it's the former then when user has selected their file, use Reader API to check the bytes (write to array and check array position for codec type) ELSE if the latter then you must load a small section of file bytes. Also note that MP4 header can be at the back of file, in such a case the server must handle range requests for skipping to the end bytes.

Comment: PS: If you can read a section of the MP4 into an array I can help you check the array values for codec type. Reading might be thru Fetch or AJAX or maybe even PHP. You want to find "stsd" which is "sample description" which is bytes `73 74 73 64` so in a for loop find as `if myArray[i] == 0x73 && if myArray[i+1] == 0x74 && ...etc etc` then when `i` reaches that specific 4 value sequence you can check if it's audio or video description by skipping ahead 16 positions and check if those 4 values make `avc1`, if yes then you have video description so skip ahead 90 positions to read codec type...

Comment: Show testable code for reading a section of MP4 into array and I'll modify your code to read the codec type.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I tried to load some bytes and analyse it with [mux.js](https://github.com/videojs/mux.js/) lib (`muxjs.mp4.tools.inspect(bytes)`) and failed.. maybe I was not far away but someone told me a smart hack to know what i want, I will edit an answer there!

Comment: @VC.One but your bytes analysis solution is really interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigation trying to analyse first bytes with [mux.js](https://github.com/videojs/mux.js/) lib, I got this nice hack from [github](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/5307#issuecomment-867720618):

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (event) => {
  if(event.target.videoHeight === 0) {
    console.log('cant play video..');
  }
});
```

The idea is to check the [videoHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/videoHeight) property value after video initialization:

- If we have a 'real' value, it means browser is able to read it.
- If we have `0`, browser can't read it.

Comment: Nice hack and it makes sense about video height.

Comment: Awesome! been searching to find ways to identify if the provided MP4 video is playable and this hack perfectly works out.